# Switch between activities in React-native (Android)

Tags: android, react-native, android-activity

In React-native I have DefaultActivity or MainActivity in android so the react-native app will display content in MainActivity.

If I create My own activity in android in the react-native platform can I Switch between MainActivity(Default Activity in react-native) and My CustomeActivity in react-native parallelly?

**For suppose I had my MainActivity and in CustomeActivity I had Mapbox integrated in native android. Is it possible to switch between MainActivity and CustomeActivity? Does it work in react-native framework**

```
  <application...... >
    <activity
          android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name=".MyCustomeActivity" />
   </application>
```